# Desktop entry to convert audio/video files (naming question)

Tags: .desktop, ffmpeg

My question:  I'd like to create a desktop entry in (kde dolphins servicemenu) to convert audio/video files.

I have tried it with the follwing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Convertwav2Mp3
Icon=audio-x-flac
MimeType=audio/*
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action Convertwav2Mp3]
Exec=ffmpeg -i %f -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k .out.mp3 && mv .out.mp3 %f
Icon=audio-x-flac
Name=Convertwav2Mp3
```

Works like a charm when put in /usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/.

BUT: The mv command renames the output file to the original filename with its file extension (which is wav but should be mp3).

How can i change the command as to rename it from file.wav to file.mp3 within the Exec field?

Answer (score 0):

## Option #1: append the .mp3

```
Exec=ffmpeg -i %f -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k %f.mp3
```

This will result in e.g. converting

```
my_file.wav
```

to

```
my_file.wav.mp3
```

which may not be desirable.

Fun fact: there was used to be the `%n` key that gave the base name like this:

```
Exec=ffmpeg -i %f -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k %n.mp3
```

The FreeDesktop spec has listed this as deprecated from version 1.0:

> Deprecated `Exec` field codes: ...  %n (the base name of a file) ...

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html

This may have worked in older versions of Dolphin, but in the version I used (17.12.3), the `%n` key does the same as the `%f` key, so this will not work as desired.

## Option #2: use bash parameter expansion

To get this instead:

```
my_file.mp3
```

we will need to remove the file extension.
This can be accomplished using
[bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
Exec=bash -c 'wavfile='\''%f'\''; mp3file="${wavfile%.wav}.mp3"; ffmpeg -i '\''%f'\'' -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "$mp3file"'
```

We have to invoke bash explicitly because the `Exec` key is passed through `/bin/sh`, which does not support this syntax.

## Caveats

Both of these options will work with filenames that have spaces.
However, they will not work as expected in other cases, such as:

- If the MP3 filename already exists, it will silently fail.
- If the WAV filename contains a parameter expansion string
  such as `$0` or `$USER` it will silently fail.
- If the WAV filename contains a command substitution string such as `` `date` `` or `$(date)` it will silently fail.
- If the WAV filename is e.g. `example.WAV` instead of `example.wav`, it will result in `example.WAV.mp3`.

To make these problems more tractable and easier to debug, I would recommend writing a separate shell script and invoking it directly; there are many examples:

- [How to convert a m4a sound file to mp3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65331/how-to-convert-a-m4a-sound-file-to-mp3)
- [How can I convert audio from ogg to mp3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442997/how-can-i-convert-audio-from-ogg-to-mp3)
- [bulk/batch convert mp3 files to ogg via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147944/bulk-batch-convert-mp3-files-to-ogg-via-command-line)
- [Converting mp4 to mp3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84584/converting-mp4-to-mp3)
- [convert a folder of mp4's to mp3's with ffmpeg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197461/convert-a-folder-of-mp4s-to-mp3s-with-ffmpeg)

## Further comments

As an aside, you may already know this, but the desktop file can be copied to

```
~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
```

instead of

```
/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
```

which is useful if you want to install it for a single user or don't have root privileges.

Finally, I would recommend using

```
MimeType=audio/x-wav
```

instead of

```
MimeType=audio/*
```

since this only works on WAV files.

Related questions:

- [Double file extension with FFmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079725/double-file-extension-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is specifically about the correct renaming without the doubled file extensions....The command itself already works fine...

Comment: The `Exec` field does not have any facilities for manipulating filenames. Your current example uses the shell to call ffmpeg and run multiple commands, but it could just as easily use a Python script, compiled C program, etc. Could you explain your requirements in more detail?